# jQuery Tabs PAUSE on click (and then resume after set amount of time)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, rotation

I am using the jquery slideshow as demonstrated here: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/

My code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 6000, true);
});
```

I want to make it so that when a user clicks on one of those tabs, it causes a delay (of maybe 20 seconds). Inside this...

```
jQuery(".ui-tabs-nav").click(function() {
//ADD PAUSE/DELAY CODE HERE...
});
```

I've tried all the following (none work) insid

```
setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#featured").tabs("rotate", 6000, true); }, 20000);
```

and

```
jQuery("#featured").delay(20000).tabs("rotate",6000,true);
```

and randomly this too

```
jQuery("#featured").tabs().stop();
```

I also tried changing the initial "tabs("rotate")... part to look like this:

```
jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 6000, false);
```

But that only makes the rotation stop completely stop on click. Adding the call back in on my .click(function()... to get it restarted - is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the rotation you need to pass a null value, then you can delay and continue:

```
jQuery(".ui-tabs-nav").click(function() {
    jQuery("#featured").tabs("rotate", null);
    setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery("#featured").tabs("rotate", 6000, true);
    }, 20000);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to add the delay. If I initially set jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 6000, false); then it still stops completely, if I set initially set it as jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 6000, true); then there is no delay at all...